# Show extra columns when hovering in a scatter plot with hvplot

Tags: python, hvplot, holoviz

I'm trying to add a label or hover column to the points in a scatter plot, but to no avail.

For use as example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.read_csv('http://assets.holoviews.org/macro.csv', '\t')

df.query("year == 1966").hvplot.scatter(x="gdp", y="unem")
```

results in the picture below. If I hover over this item I cannot see, which country is represented by the dot (which makes it rather useless). I could use the additional keyword `color="country"`in the scatterplot call. This would lead to an additional legend (which could be turned off) and the value country: countryname is added to the hover field.

[image: Scatter plot gdp vs. unemployment, country indicator is missing]

Is there an option that just adds the column to my hover without adding a legend and changing the color?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can **use keyword hover_cols** to add additional columns to your hover.

Documentation: https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Customization.html

> hover_cols (default=[]): list or str 
>   Additional columns to add to the hover tool or 'all' which will includes all columns (including indexes if use_index is True).

So in your example if you would like to **add specific columns to your hover**:

```
# use keyword hover_cols to add additional columns when hovering
df.hvplot.scatter(x="gdp", y="unem", hover_cols=['country', 'year'])
```

Or if you want to **include all additional columns to your hover**:

```
df.hvplot.scatter(x="gdp", y="unem", hover_cols='all')
```

Or if you want to **include all columns to hover, but not the index**:

```
df.hvplot.scatter(x="gdp", y="unem", hover_cols='all', use_index=False)
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for. With regards to usability hvplot is a huge step forward coming from matplotlib.

Comment: couldn't agree more, its nice, fast, easy and most of all: interactive :)

Comment: if one of the columns is not numeric, hover_cols='all' crashes

Comment: Is there a way to remove a column from being displayed? For example when defining custom color or marker, but you don't want it displayed.